# Editing Discord bot to accept another bot's commands

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make my Discord bot able to respond to another bot's commands. So the other bots can use my bot. What can I do to do this for specific commands? What should I add to this? Thanks for all your help.

```py
@bot.command()  
async def dothat(ctx):
    await ctx.send("!blabla")
```

Comment: I think this is not possible but I am not sure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if a bot receives a command from anyone it will execute, even itself.

Comment: @IsmailHafeez No, none of these Discord bots get any other bots command.

Comment: The reason I said this is if I was to create a function to send the function name the bot would see that as a command and would infinitely loop itself.

Comment: Your bot should already respond to commands from other bots, unless you have manually disabled that by checking for it in on_message

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible on discord.py only in discord.js and discord.jda

Answer (score 0):

Other bots will probably block bots from contacting it, as it's policy on several discord listing sites (such as [top.gg](https://top.gg)). By default however, other bots can contact other bots.

Bots can detect whether its a bot contacting it through the use of

```
ctx.message.author.bot
```

which is a boolean that is true when the author of the message is a bot.